# Is it possible to keep a <td> at the top?

Tags: html

I have this table, which is how it will look when a user posts. When a large amount of content is entered in the second td, the first td does what it should naturally do and center itself with the second one. Here is what it looks like:

http://puu.sh/YdaE

Is it possible to make it so the first td stays at the top and doesn't center itself with the second one? Because it looks kind of silly when it does...

Here is the basic jist the code:

```
<div id="feed">
    <div class="post">
         <table>
              <tr>
                   <td><img src="images/profile-pic.jpg"></td>
                   <td>
                       <div class="name">Kevin Jones</div>
                       <div class="message">Hanging out with my girlfriend, etc.</div>
                   </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
     </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think you might want to use floated divs in this situation since it's not tabular data. Plus, CSS + tables can be tricky/annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with CSS.

```
vertical-align: top;
```

So you could just give a class to your first TD and apply the above-mentioned CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but if you want to prevent the image on the first td to be vertically aligned just specify vertical alignment via HTML attribute as shown here:

```
<div id="feed">
    <div class="post">
         <table>
              <tr>
                   <td valign="top"><img src="images/profile-pic.jpg"></td>
                   <td>
                       <div class="name">Kevin Jones</div>
                       <div class="message">Hanging out with my girlfriend, etc.</div>
                   </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `valign="top"` attribute to the `td` tag